# Comparing polygon boundaries in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, linestring, differences

I've to compare two polygon layers, 'land_use' and 'land_parcels', in PostGIS. My aim is to create linestrings, where boundaries of 'land_use' polygons do not match boundaries of 'land_parcel' polygons.

[image]

[image]

[image]

A similar question has already been asked as [How to create lines to visualize differences between polygon features in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180707).

Can anyone help me adapting the query posted by Mike T?

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () rn, *
FROM (
  SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_SymDifference(ST_Snap(luse, lparcels, tol), ST_Snap(lparcels, luse, tol)))).*
  FROM (
    SELECT ST_Union(DISTINCT land_use_only.geom) luse, ST_Union(DISTINCT land_parcels_only.geom) lparcels, 1e-5 tol
    FROM (
      SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) geom FROM land_use
      EXCEPT SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) geom FROM land_parcels
    ) land_use_only,
    (
      SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) geom FROM land_parcels
      EXCEPT SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) geom FROM land_use
    ) land_parcels_only
  ) s
) s;
```

Comment: Can you post your data.

Comment: PostGIS schema backup: http://cloud.directupload.net/8ZzV

Comment: Replacing ST_SymDifference by ST_Difference, is that the only thing I have to do? Actually, that's quite logical ;)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that long query is really necessary? What's wrong with:

```
SELECT 1 gid, ST_Difference(ST_Union(lparcels.geom), ST_Union(luse.geom)) geom
FROM boundary_test.land_use luse,  boundary_test.land_parcels lparcels
```

Or if you really need single part geometry:

```
SELECT (dump_geom).path[1],(dump_geom).geom geom
FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Difference(ST_Union(lparcels.geom), ST_Union(luse.geom)))) dump_geom
FROM boundary_test.land_use luse,  boundary_test.land_parcels lparcels) t
```

If you want to snap vertices, you shouldn't `ST_Snap` twice, you should only snap to the most accurate reference, if land_parcels is more accurate you should:

```
ST_Snap(luse.geom, lparcels.geom, tolerance)
```

And shouldn't `ST_Snap(lparcels.geom, luse.geom, tolerance)`. If you snap land_parcels to land_use you will actually include misplace error to land_parcels, assuming land_parcels is more accurate.

## EDIT:

If you need to return LineString just do:

```
SELECT (dump_geom).path[1],(dump_geom).geom geom
FROM (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(ST_Difference(ST_Union(lparcels.geom), ST_Union(luse.geom))))) dump_geom
FROM boundary_test.land_use luse,  boundary_test.land_parcels lparcels) t
```

### Snapping

You should not notice visually the error included by incorrect snap 'cause it may enter very tiny difference polygons. See what I'm talking about snapping.

If you snap A->B:

[image]

Or snap B->A:

[image]

If you snap both (like you are in the query you posted) you will just switch places:

[image]

The right approach is to first snap features to the most accurate mapping and then snap the most accurate mapping to the already snapped features. So if A is more accurate, snap B to A (generate a snapped B), then snap A to snapped B.

### Difference vs Symmetric difference

You should also be aware about what each one does.

Symmetric difference doesn't care about the order of operands, because its result is what ***A has but B doesn't*** + what ***B has but A doesn't***.

Difference will care about the order of operands. If it is `A - B` you will get what A has but B doesn't.

Be careful on code you blindly copy and paste. You have to understand what's going on or you may get results you think are ok, but in fact they are not.

## FINALLY

I think this is what you wanted:

```
SELECT 1 gid, ST_Difference(lu.geom, lp.geom) geom
FROM 
    (SELECT ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom)) geom FROM land_use) lu, 
    (SELECT ST_Union(ST_Boundary(geom)) geom FROM land_parcels) lp
```

You can ST_Dump to break linestrings.

Comment: The query posted above returns polygon features. I want to create linestrings where 'land_use' boundaries do not math 'land_parcel' boundaries. Mike's query works properly after replacing ST_SymDifference with ST_Difference.

Comment: It is really easy, just convert it by using `ST_Boundary`, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the query does not return the results I need. Please take a closer  look at the  question.

Comment: Ah, now I've got it, you want the "new" boundaries included by land_use which didn't exist before in land_parcels, right? I've updated above.

Comment: Thanks, this one seems to return the expected results. But Mike's query is much faster on large data sets (e.g. 2.5 sec vs 109 sec for a few hundred features).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just run an erase and end up with any stray line segments or add an erase to your script. Could you just covert your land use polygon to a polyline and run an intersect to see which areas actually overlap?